# Any tools for measuring the security of a site?

Tags: security, asp.net

I'm wondering is there any tool for measuring or testing the security of a website ?

I've written some ASP.NET web-app , So i would like measure the security of my own application and if there is any whole like sql-Injection or XSS , i could fix that .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several good apps you can look at for this, some of them available for free.

[Netsparker](http://www.netsparker.com) has a community edition that covers XSS and SQLi

[Acunetix WVS](http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/) also have a community edition that can review sites for XSS.

On top of that there's some free tools that you could use

[skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) is a free security scanner from a google researcher

[W3AF](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/) is a a free web app. scanner

BTW if you've got more questions on the security side of things, there's a dedicated Stack Exchange site at security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

http://cirt.net/nikto2

There are dozens of application testers for things like that.  Above is Nikto a free tool to do just what you are asking for.  Depending on the depth and breadth of your application you may want to consider bringing in some outside help to better assess it.

Comment: Nikto is a good tool looking for known issues in published apps and some other classes of problem, but it doesn't scan for SQL Injection or Cross site scripting in custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Great comments thus far.
Armitage can also scan for web application exploits.
A comprehensive maintained list can also be found here http://sectools.org/tag/web-scanners/