# Ultimate security checklist

Tags: security, best-practices

I'm looking for a complete security checklist that will allow me to secure my websites. After some research here is what I got:

-**use SSL to protect authenticated content**
-**tighten the server TCP/IP stack** (e.g. enabling syn cookies, limiting the number of connections by ips.., allowing only public access to port 80...)
-**prevent illegitimate bots from crawling your website** to save bandwidth for legitimate users (e.g. using `mod_rewrite` and blocking based on HTTP user agent)
-**review your code for common security mistakes** (e.g. with [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main))
-**use an application firewall for additional security** (e.g. `mod_security`)
-**test your application security with assessment tools** (e.g. these questions on  ["webmasters"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/any-tools-for-measuring-the-security-of-a-site) or ["serverfault"](https://serverfault.com/questions/275794/looking-for-a-good-web-penetration-testing-client))

Any input to complete this list would be appreciated. Also information as to how much money/time is usually required to carry out these steps would allow a cost-effective approach to security.

Comment: Made community wiki as per the [faq]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered at: [what should a developer know about websites?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site) Which covers security, and everything else, performance, SEO, etc...